# How to set or change default height of table in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to change table height by openpyxl,and I wish a more large height value as default at first,then I can set auto wrap line to make my table more beautiful,but I don't know How To Change Default Height.The only way I know so far to change table height is setting the value of row_dimension[idx].height but with this method ,the height will be fixed and some lines with too many words will overflow the cell which isn't what I want.

I have tried to change default table height by changing the value of the sheet_obj.sheet_format.defaultRowHeight = 40 but it seems its just a fixed value which can't be changed

```py
#this way get the fixed height
for i,_ in enumerate(collection_sheet.rows):
        collection_sheet.row_dimensions[i+1].height=60

#this way didn't work
    collection_sheet.sheet_format.defaultRowHeight = 60
```

I expect all cell with a default height value and auto wrap line will finally determine the height of each row

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is, unfortunately, incorrect. Determining column widths or row heights is something that applications such as MS Excel do, largely because they are dependent upon the device and operating system being used. openpyxl is a library for the file format only, so if you need to change those values you will need to write your own code to do this.